# reading data file containing multiple ID's into different csvs

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, import

Given a file with the following data structure:

```
FIXED=0
LINES=1
POINTS=5
390 397
390 396
389 395
389 394
388 393
IMAGE=Name1.jpg
ID=1 
FIXED=0
LINES=1
POINTS=4
255 503
256 502
256 501
256 500
IMAGE=Name2.jpg
ID=2 
FIXED=0
LINES=1
POINTS=6
262 431
262 430
262 429
262 428
262 427
262 426
IMAGE=Name3.jpg
ID=3
```

Were:

- The lines between `FIXED` and `ID` belong to an individual
- The numbers represent two columns of variables

How would we read in the data and then transform into individual .csv files were:

- The name of each .csv is the line after `IMAGE=` Name1, Name2, Name3...
- First column of data of `Name1.csv` is the first column of numbers (`390 390 389 389 388`)
- Second column of data of `Name1.csv` is the second column of numbers (`397 396 395 394 393`)
- The same for `Name2.csv`, `Name3.csv`....
- `FIXED=0`, `LINES=1`, `POINTS=5`, `ID=1` can be dispensed

Please note that the number of rows between `POINTS` and `IMAGE` is not contant

Answer (score 1):

You could try this method:

```
library(stringr)

# Read the data from file
data <- readLines("your_file.txt")

# Initialize variables
current_individual <- NULL
current_points <- NULL
current_data <- NULL

# Process each line of the data
for (line in data) {
  # Check if the line starts with "IMAGE="
  if (str_starts(line, "IMAGE=")) {
    # Extract the individual name from the line
    individual_name <- str_remove(line, "IMAGE=")
    individual_name <- str_remove(individual_name, ".jpg")
    
    # If there is existing data, save it to a CSV file
    if (!is.null(current_individual) && !is.null(current_data)) {
      csv_file <- paste0(current_individual, ".csv")
      write.csv(current_data, file = csv_file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
    
    # Initialize variables for the new individual
    current_individual <- individual_name
    current_points <- NULL
    current_data <- NULL
    
  } else if (str_starts(line, "POINTS=")) {
    # Extract the number of points from the line
    num_points <- as.numeric(str_remove(line, "POINTS="))
    
    # Initialize variables for the points
    current_points <- num_points
    current_data <- matrix(nrow = num_points, ncol = 2)
    
  } else if (str_detect(line, "\\d+ \\d+")) {
    # Extract the two numbers from the line
    numbers <- str_split(line, " ")[[1]]
    
    # Append the numbers to the current data
    current_data <- rbind(current_data, as.numeric(numbers))
  }
}

# Save the last individual's data to a CSV file
if (!is.null(current_individual) && !is.null(current_data)) {
  csv_file <- paste0(current_individual, ".csv")
  write.csv(current_data, file = csv_file, row.names = FALSE)
}
```